# How can I approach this vending machine?

Tags: java, loops

I have an assignment in Java to make a vending machine that displays items and prices using the `printf` tool and requests the user to enter the money they have. It then asks the user to make a selection with a character, exiting if they type x and prompting for another try if they type in an invalid character. It also keeps a running total of the money they have left and doesn't allow them to buy something they don't have the money for. After user 1 is done, it is then open for the next user to enter the amount of money they have and choose an item but with the items the first user chose absent.  This cycle repeats until nothing is left in the machine or a user ends the program. Each user should be able to buy as many of each item as they want (one by one) until there is no more of that item.

Comment: Seems like user 1 and user 2 cannot both buy milk. Well, can user 1 buy *two* milk?

Comment: Yes, it's meant that each user can buy as many of each item as they want until there is nothing left.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a class to indicate a type of item.

```
public class Item { // or without public
    private String name;
    private char choice;
    private double price;
    private int amount; // or name it *quant*-what I can't spell that word
    // Constructors, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

And you can use a list to handle them. This initializes items in the vender:

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
items.add(new Item("Milk", 'a', 2.00, 5));
// Add other items
```

And this prints all items:

```
for(Item item : items)
    System.out.printf(/* format string */, item.getName(), /* other arguments */);
```

And this handles actual purchase:

```
boolean foundItem = false;
for(Item item : items) {
    if(item.getChoice() == choice) {
        foundItem = true;
        // Handle not enough money, not enough amount, etc. or sell it
    }
}
if(!foundItem) {
    // Invalid entry
}
```

And this it our main:

```
public static void main(String s) {
    // Initialize items in the vender
    // Initialize other things needed
    while(/* has items to sell */) {
        // Read a double as customer's money
        // `break;` if is a program-exit request
        while(true) {
            // Print current items
            // Read a character as customer choice, to lower case
            // `break;` if is an customer-exit request
            // Handle the actual purchase request
        }
        // Print customer exit message
    }
    // Print program exit message
}
```

Well, it's your responsibility to fill in the blank.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `while(choice==...)` loop never ends.
The variable `choice` is never altered within the loop and so once you get in you'll never come out.
You should be prompting the user to enter a new choice inside the loop.